# Change position of plotly hover box R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I would like to change the position of the hover box in a `plotly` bar chart. Rather than have it popup on the left or right, I would like it to popup above the bar. Is this possible? I've been googling this and staring at the Plotly R reference page for a couple hours with no luck.

Here's a sample:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10*10) %>% 
  plotly::plot_ly(data = .) %>%
  plotly::add_trace(x = ~x, 
                    y = ~y, 
                    type = 'bar', 
                    hoverinfo = "text", 
                    text = ~y)
```

Comment: ```g <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10*10) %>% 
  plotly::plot_ly(data = .) %>%
  plotly::add_trace(x = ~y, 
                    y = ~x, 
                    type = 'bar', 
                    hoverinfo = "text", 
                    text = ~y,
                    orientation = "h")``` is this close enough? I know it can be done in `plotly.js` but in `r` I just could not find anything related.

Comment: @M-M Thanks, but I need to keep columns. Plotly in R seems to be missing a lot of features. Even bolding text is a chore.